# Do class/static variables have access to static methods?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

Forgive me if this question is obvious, but from what I've read on Python's OOP tutorials none of them mention how to have a static variable store a static method. In my code I tried:

```
class Features:
    a_static_variable = 1
    a_static_variable_that_references_a_static_function = Features.func1

    @staticmethod
    def func1(blah):
        print(blah)
```

When trying to run this I received:

```
NameError: name 'Features' is not defined
```

Is it possible for a class method to reference a static method in its own class? If so, how do I do this. I tried replacing Features with nothing and self but as I expected those made no sense as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a case of `func1` not being defined yet.

It should work if you reorder:

```
class Features:
    a_static_variable = 1

    @staticmethod
    def func1(blah):
        print(blah)

    a_static_variable_that_references_a_static_function = func1
```

Comment: While all true, this doesn't explain the `NameError` caused by referencing a class during it's own definition. It also doesn't explain why a class method doesn't need to prepend the class names `Features`, but an instance method does.

Comment: Those are other questions (even interesting questions), but not the OP's question.  I prefer not to get bogged down in extra details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just define the function first:

```
class Features:
    @staticmethod
    def func1(blah):
        print(blah)

    a_static_variable = 1
    a_static_variable_that_references_a_static_function = func1

Features.a_static_variable_that_references_a_static_function('test')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two errors (explained in the other answers). This example may help you understand what's going on.

```
class Example:
    class_variable = 'class_variable'

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        print('static_method')

    class_method = static_method

    print(locals())

    def instance_method(self):
        print(instance_method)
        print(locals())
```

When this code is run, without instantiating a member of this class, the output is:

```
creating the class:
{'class_variable': 'class_variable', 
 '__module__': '__main__', 
 'static_method': <staticmethod object at 0x0135E5F0>, 
 'class_method': <staticmethod object at 0x0135E5F0>
}
```

So, while creating the class, a scope is created in which all of the names in that dictionary are accessible.

Now let's look at what happens when we do this:

```
example = Example()
example.instance_method()
```

Nothing happens when you instantiate an object, but calling `instance_method` will print the local variable(s) accessible to that scope.

```
instance_method
{'self': <__main__.Example instance at 0x01810210>}
```

Now, you are probably used to creating instance methods that reference class variables.

```
def other_instance_method(self):
    print(Example.class_variable)
```

Here, `Example` is not present in the local scope. In order to find it, the global scope needs to be searched (i.e. `globals`). Note that instead of explicitly referencing `Example`, we could access the the class variable from the `self` object itself.

```
def other_instance_method(self):
    print(self.class_variable)
```

You can do some testing yourself by printing `locals()` and `globals()` from various places to get a grip on how the scope changes.

Comment: Actually, `self.__class__.class_variable` indirection is not necessary.  Just `self.class_variable` is usual here.